# Got email about v2 API, can't find endpoints

Tags: dropbox-api

I got this email from dropbox dev:

[image]

I clicked all the links looking for the v2 endpoints but cant find it anywhere. I click documentation and then it tells me to pick an lanuagues like js or something.

Is this a bug in the email? Did they forget to point to the v2 endpoints that are found here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation

I know this endpoint link only because someone on stack linked me to it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close, since this doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, but thanks for the feedback on the site. The first link in that email goes to https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation, and if you click on "HTTP" on that page, you get to what you're looking for. (This is the same as the "HTTP" link on the left-hand nav of the site.)

Is there a different phrase you were looking for other than "HTTP" that would have helped to make this stand out?

Also, the second link goes to the API Explorer, which also lists the endpoints. Each endpoint there has a "documentation" link which goes to the appropriate endpoint in the HTTP documentation.